# Move the last element in the node (of a multidimensional php array) at the beginning?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hello guys i would to move the last element in the node (of a multidimensional php array) at the beginning...

This is my array:

```
$arr= array(    
 array(2,3,4,5,1),
 array(3,4,5,6,2),
 array(4,5,6,7,3)    
);
```

and this is the output that i would to have:

```
Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( 
   [0] => 1 
   [1] => 2 
   [2] => 3 
   [3] => 4 
   [4] => 5 
 ) 
 [1] => Array ( 
   [0] => 2 
   [1] => 3 
   [2] => 4 
   [3] => 5 
   [4] => 6 
 ) 
 [2] => Array ( 
   [0] => 3 
   [1] => 4 
   [2] => 5 
   [3] => 6 
   [4] => 7 
 ) 
)
```

I created this code that works fine

```
$number= count($arr);

for($a= 0; $a < $number; $a++){
 $element=  $arr[$a][4];    
 unset($arr[$a][4]);
 array_unshift($arr[$a],$element);
}
```

but i would know if there are other faster and efficient methods...
Thanks a lot and sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 1):

Given the input you provided and the output, this is quicker to type:

```
array_map('sort', $arr);
```

Whether it runs faster or gives the desired result - I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

A correct answer that doesn't depend on the sort order of the values inside the array.

```
foreach($array as &$element) {
 array_unshift($element,array_pop($element));
}
```